# Sequelize - Cannot read property 'getQueryInterface' of undefined

Tags: sequelize.js

Here's hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a table of "trigger" words that trigger certain behaviors in my app. The app has been running for some months now, but *sometimes*, during a call to `findAll`, the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getQueryInterface' of undefined
    at Model.get (C:\Users\Me\Projects\api\project-name-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:104:40)
    at Model.get (C:\Users\Me\Projects\api\project-name-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:110:17)
    at Model.getTableName (C:\Users\Me\Projects\api\project-name-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1087:15)
    at Model.findAll (C:\Users\Me\Projects\api\project-name-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1350:19)
    at getSession.then.s (C:\Users\Me\Projects\api\project-name-api\lib\message-interpreter.js:148:15)
```

It also stops the app from running.

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: false == true
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:280:3)
```

(Is this even related to findAll? Is this a random bug? Because...) The context of my `findAll` is pretty simple. Here's a sample call:

```
let words = 'hello world';
Trigger.findAll({
    raw: true,
    where: {
      // Find any available trigger word in the message
      word: { $in: msg.split(' ') }
    }
}).then(...)
```

...And that's all I've got. The bunch of other similar questions seem to be caused by some incorrect model definition, but I've checked mine and it *seems* to be correct. Only the `Trigger` model (out of a bunch of other, more complex models) is affected by this.

The stack trace brings me to the definition of `findAll`: it turns out that `this.modelManager.sequelize` is undefined for some reason, but I'm not sure why or what I should be looking out for to correct this. I'd appreciate some guidance!

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake on my part.

I trimmed down my app code to the following, where another unrelated model was including an attribute with a function call. However, I used a pure string instead of `sequelize.fn()` with the appropriate `sequelize.col()` and `sequelize.literal()`. The `INTERVAL <interval> MINUTES` part had thrown me off-track, and I forgot about the `literal` function. The code "worked", but with the side-effect shown in the above error.

```
Session.findOrCreate({
  having: {
    startDate: {
      $lt: sequelize.col('expiry')
    }
  },
  raw: true,
  attributes: {
    include: [
      ['DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL sessionTimeout MINUTE)', 'expiry']
    ]
  }
});
```

While this seems to resolve the issue, I'm not sure I understand the root cause. Why is the `sequelize` property suddenly undefined? Why was this behavior not caught as an error already, instead of propagating into something like this? Perhaps I should bring it up with the Sequelize team.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, upgrading the module `sequelize-typescript` from `1.1.0` to `2.1.0` resolved the issue.